# New user changes post after I answered

Tags: support, new-users, posting

A new user completely changed [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610411/geometry-problem-on-triangles-finding-the-length) question after I answered it.  Is this allowed?  I suspect this is because new users cannot post more than 2 questions.  I feel angered by this, as it wasted my hard work.

Comment: No, this is not allowed, feel free to roll it back (I have done so for you now). In general, you'd better ask these kind of questions on Mathematics' own meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ – there are more people there who can help you.

Comment: Note that the question can be considered off-topic because of lack of work from the OP's side (we don't know his/her skill level, so it's hard to give a fitting answer).